# The type or namespace name 'Exchange' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run my ASP.net app I get this error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
```

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Exchange' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
   Line 06:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   Line 07:  using System.Data.OleDb;
   Line 08:  using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data; // error
   Line 09:  using System.Net;
   Line 10:  using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: It would be nice to include an actual question in the question, so we do not have to use the [psychic debugging powers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/21/641456.aspx) to figure out what you want to know (I took a stab at it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing a reference to microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll assembly.  At least the ASP.NET cannot find that assembly when it tries to compile the code.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your Target Framework versions match in all projects of your solution. I personally have had issues with .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. Once I switched it to .NET Framework 4, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a page compilation error. To resolve it you need to look into the [`compilation.assemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) configuration and [`pages.namespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms164642%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which let you configure the assemblies and namespaces used in the generated code for pages. The other way to ensure assemblies are referenced during page compilation is to mark them as **"Copy Local"** in your solution.

In your case you are probably referencing an Exchange dll in your project. Mark it as "Copy Local" and the error should resolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use

```
   using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
```

You have to install Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices via the NuGet manager.